# Uploading file to directory using shared network path

Tags: php, directory, upload

I am unsure why I am able to read files from a directory but not write to it.  It is on a shared network path.

I have confirmation from my networking team that "modify permissions" are already in place for the user account.

Here is what I have used to check if the file path is valid:

```
<?php
  $filename = '//server-name/folder1/folder1/folder3/filename.txt';
  
  if (file_exists($filename)) {echo "good";}
  else{echo "bad";}
?>
```

Using the above, I was able to get an output of "good" in the console.

Then I used the following is see if I can list all of the files in the directory:

```
<?php
  $dir = '//server-name/folder1/folder2/folder3';
  $files1 = scandir($dir);
  $files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
    
  print_r($files1);
  print_r($files2);
?>
```

Using the above, I was successfully able to print out all of the files in the directory.

Here is the code I'm having problems with:

```
<?php
  $filename = "newfile";

  $thecall = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL SP_SVC_ALLOCATION($servicecodes)");

  $out = array(); 

  while($row = $thecall->fetch_assoc()){
    $out[] = $row;
  }

  $file = fopen("//server-name/folder1/folder2/folder3/$filename.txt", 'w');
    foreach ($out as $fields) {
      fputcsv($file, $fields);
    }

  if($file){$result = "File was uploaded";}
  else{$result = "File failed to upload";}  
?>
```

Using the above, the output is "File failed to upload".

Why am I able to read from the path, but not upload?

As stated, I was assured the permissions are already set.  Do I need to get full permissions on the shared network drive?

Comment: $out is not defined

Comment: My apologies.  I did not list the $out variable.  I used it to fill in data from a stored procedure call.  My question has been updated.

Comment: is something in the error.log of the server ? some warnings ?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Any upload has nothing to do with a database. Shoose one problem to work with.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - If you are referring to the addition of the "mysqli" tag, I only added that since I included the stored procedure call.  If it was unnecessary to include the tag, then thank you for removing it.

Comment: I am more referring to *narrowing down* the problem you are asking for help with. Which actual part of the code doesn't work? SQL query? Upload? Storing the uploaded file? Something else? We have no means to run your code. You have to provide the relevant information in order to get any help. at least provide the error message you get

Comment: @YourCommonSense - The first comment here from aryan agarwal stated my $out variable was undefined.  I simply added that variable and included how that variable was used.  My problem remains the same - unable to upload the file.  My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the network path just didn't have the full permissions for the user.  It has been updated and now I am able to upload to the path without issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$file = fopen("//server-name/folder1/folder2/folder3/$filename.txt", 'w');
$csv="";
foreach ($out as $fields){
    $csv.= implode(',',$fields)."\n";
}

 
fwrite($file,$csv);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: No luck. I appreciate the attempt.  I did not downvote you.